# How to save a recognised regular expression in a column in the same txt file that the pattern was found?

Tags: regex, unix, grep, output

I have a file with many columns (1st row)

```
TRINITY_DN3472760_c4_g4 TRINITY_DN3472760_c4_g4_i1  DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex`DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:2-361,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:4.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex TRINITY_DN3472760_c4_g4_i1.p2   2-373[+]    DHAS_AQUAE^DHAS_AQUAE^Q:1-120,H:214-332^53.333%ID^E:1.37e-32^RecName: Full=Aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase {ECO:0000255|HAMAP-Rule:MF_02121};^Bacteria; Aquificae; Aquificales; Aquificaceae; Aquifex  PF02774.15^Semialdhyde_dhC^Semialdehyde dehydrogenase, dimerisation domain^1-108^E:6.4e-24  COG0136^Catalyzes the NADPH-dependent formation of L-aspartate- semialdehyde (L-ASA) by the reductive dephosphorylation of L- aspartyl-4-phosphate (By similarity)  KEGG:aae:aq_1866`KO:K00133  KEGG:aae:aq_1866`KO:K00133  GO:0005737^cellular_component^cytoplasm`GO:0004073^molecular_function^aspartate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase activity`GO:0003942^molecular_function^N-acetyl-gamma-glutamyl-phosphate reductase activity`GO:0051287^molecular_function^NAD binding`GO:0050661^molecular_function^NADP binding`GO:0071266^biological_process^'de novo' L-methionine biosynthetic process`GO:0019877^biological_process^diaminopimelate biosynthetic process`GO:0009097^biological_process^isoleucine biosynthetic process`GO:0009089^biological_process^lysine biosynthetic process via diaminopimelate`GO:0009088^biological_process^threonine biosynthetic process   GO:0003942^molecular_function^N-acetyl-gamma-glutamyl-phosphate reductase activity`GO:0016620^molecular_function^oxidoreductase activity, acting on the aldehyde or oxo group of donors, NAD or NADP as acceptor`GO:0046983^molecular_function^protein dimerization activity`GO:0008652^biological_process^cellular amino acid biosynthetic process`GO:0055114^biological_process^oxidation-reduction process`GO:0005737^cellular_component^cytoplasm   GGAGCGTAAGGTCACCTGGGAGACGCGCAAGATCATGGACCTGCCCGACCTCCCTGTGTCGTGCACGTGCGTGCGCATCCCCACGCTGCGCGCGCACGGCGAGTCGATCACCATCGAGACGGAGAAGCCGATCAACATGGAGAGGGCCTACGCTGTGCTCAACGAGGCCTCCGGCGTCGTCGTCGTCGACGACACCTCGAAGAACCTCTACCCGATGCCGATCACCGCCTCGACCAAGTTCGACGTCGAGGTCGGCCGCCTCCGCATCAACGACGTCTTCGGCGAGAACGGCCTCGACATGTTCGTCGTCGGCGATCAGCTCCTCCGCGGCGCGGCGCTCAACGCCGTCCTCATCGCGGAGGCCGTCATGTAAACTTGTTTACACCCGCGCCGCCACTCGTGCTGTTTGCTGCCGCCGGCCCGCTTCGGCCCAAACCGCGACGCCCTTGCGTGGCTTGGC    ERKVTWETRKIMDLPDLPVSCTCVRIPTLRAHGESITIETEKPINMERAYAVLNEASGVVVVDDTSKNLYPMPITASTKFDVEVGRLRINDVFGENGLDMFVVGDQLLRGAALNAVLIAEAVM*
```

One of these columns has a few annotations that can look like this:

```
KEGG:aag:AaeL_AAEL000291`KO:K02155
KEGG:aag:AaeL_AAEL003872
KEGG:aag:AaeL_AAEL005901`KEGG:aag:AaeL_AAEL013158`KO:K02984
KEGG:ago:AGOS_AGR122C`KO:K13126
KEGG:ame:408385`KO:K03231
```

I am interested in extracting the part with KO annotation i.e. by grep

```
grep -P 'K[0-9]{5}' myfile
```

but then I would like to save the matched pattern in the same file, let's say in column 15. Other option that could help me is if the matched pattern is kept in the same place but everything else is deleted.

So my expected result is a number that matches K[0-9]{5} that is saved in the same file.

Could anybody help me with it?

Comment: You input has got 4 fields per record, why do you say "Column 15"?

Comment: because first 14 columns are already full of information

Comment: Like `awk -F':' '{print $0 ":" $4}' file`? See https://ideone.com/TU7Oyn

Comment: well, the thing is that in my file the separator is tab, and these annotations are in column 9. I guess that your code would work if I have had just these annotations in the file with no other information.

Comment: You must provide an actual file example in the question with exact expected result.

Comment: Sure, however I don't find this informative. So this is the first row of information (14 columns). One of them looks like this (examples from 4 different rows): KEGG:aag:AaeL_AAEL000291`KO:K02155
KEGG:aag:AaeL_AAEL003872
KEGG:aag:AaeL_AAEL005901`KEGG:aag:AaeL_AAEL013158`KO:K02984
KEGG:ago:AGOS_AGR122C`KO:K13126
KEGG:ame:408385`KO:K03231. What I want is to retain from this column only pattern that matches K[0-9]{5}, either save it in column 15 or in the same column deleting everything else that does not match the pattern.

Comment: Please add at least 1 row from your file into the question body and provide an expected result.

Comment: Is that 1 line?

Comment: yes, the text in the body of the question is the 1st row

Comment: Try `awk -F"\t" '{r=$9; sub(/.*:/, "", r); print $0 "\t" r}' infile > outfile`

Comment: Could you explain this part: `(/.*:/, "", r); print $0 "\t" r}`, it adds extra line under every record/row.

Comment: It takes the value in Field 9, assigns it to `r`, removes all text up to and including last `:` and the prints the whole record and appends a tab + `r` value. I cannot repro the line addition.

Comment: Thank you! With approach of recognising last ':' I retain some of the information that I don't need, such as AaeL_AAEL003872 in a row with no KO annotation (KEGG:aag:AaeL_AAEL003872). I opened the output file in a spreadsheet program and it was popping as a new line.

Comment: Ok, check if Field 9 actually ends with the pattern you need, and only then sub the match out and add at the end of the valid line only: `awk -F"\t" '{if ($9 ~ /KO:K[0-9]{5}$/) { r=$9; sub(/.*:/, "", r); print $0 "\t" r; } else print $0; }' file > outfile`

Comment: Makes more sense now :) Thanks for your help @WiktorStribiżew!

Comment: Did you already consider using `sed`?

Comment: At some point yes. How would you do that in sed @Dominique?

Comment: The usage of `sed` is explained under this URL: "https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files". Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if Field 9 actually ends with the pattern you need, and then `sub` the match out with `sub(/.*:/, "", r)` and add at the end of the valid line only:

```
awk -F"\t" '{if ($9 ~ /KO:K[0-9]{5}$/) { r=$9; sub(/.*:/, "", r); print $0 "\t" r; } else print $0; }' file > outfile
```

Here,

- `-F"\t"` splits into fields using tab char
- `if ($9 ~ /KO:K[0-9]{5}$/)` is a condition, only if Field 9 (`$9`) ends with `KO:K` + 5 digits,

  - `r=$9;` assign the value of Field 9 to `r`
  - `sub(/.*:/, "", r);` then, remove all up to and including the last `:`
  - `print $0 "\t" r;` then, print the whole record with a tab and the `r` value
- `else`

  - `print $0;` print the record as is.